# Two-tiered models and controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

New to Rails and having a hard time envisioning how to proceed with a project.  I would like to create a simple page where users:

a) select a "project", sends to project page
b) from project page, can repeatedly query an API and get results

As I'm still wrapping my head around scaffolding and creating models and controllers, I'm wondering if the following makes sense:

```
rails generate Project person:string
rails generate API_call title:string response:text
```

I suppose my question is then, how do I link entries in the API_call table to specific projects?  Is this the "references" option?

many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scaffolding command is not correct. For generating complete resource:

```
rails g scaffold Project person:string
```

This will generate model, controller, migrations, views etc.

For generating just a model:

```
rails g model ApiCall title:string response:text
```

To list other generators, run

```
rails g
```

Note: you can use either `g` or `generator`

For relating objects you need to use Associations. Please check this link for getting basic idea http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. If you want to work with it, there is no alternative to study the doc.

Comment: One thing I would note is that you should have a good idea of what you want in your Project before running the scaffold, as you'll have to shotgun modify _form, index, show, and either edit the migration or add a new one if you want to add or remove columns.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you.  I didn't realize you could create only models and not the whole scaffold (which makes utter sense, shouldn't be surprised).  Time to read.